# Multiple Backgrounds in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

Excuse me for my bad English.

I decided to insert two different backgrounds in my wordpress blog but I found some problems. I tried to insert a fixed background at the top center and a second background that repeats vertically from the top center under the first background. Here's the code I used:

```
body {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
font: 62.5% "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Sans-Serif;
color: #000; text-align: left;
background-image: url(http://i39.servimg.com/u/f39/16/16/32/12/topgro11.jpg), url(images/bg.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat, y-repeat;
background-position: top center, top center;
}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see here -> http://www.picopod.it/ the result is disappointing... Where am I doing wrong? Thanks for your support!

***UPDATE:*** I resolved my problem by changing the "y-repeat" with "repeat-y". What a stupid error I've done! Ahahaha

Thank you all!

Comment: Your image topgro11.jpg resolves to a 404 not found error. So what do you want the bg.gif image to do that it's not doing?

Comment: Hello Katiek and thank you for your answer! What you say is very strange, because I can see clearly the picture from that link and it doesn't give me any error ... Are you sure there is really a 404?

Comment: Yes, Firebug couldn't find it. Anyway, it could be better if you put a complete example which we can run from anywhere here in the question; linking off-site doesn't help anyone else. Also please clarify the behavior you expect.

Comment: I resolved my problem by changing the "y-repeat" with "repeat-y". What a stupid error I've done! Thank you very much KatieK!